# Im trying to make this code wait untill the user prints 25 and then alert but instead it alwalys alerts and x is always 25(i just started coding))

Tags: javascript, html

```
let x = (document.getElementById("SM").value);
```

if (x = 25){alert ("THIS IS just isnt working")};
console.log(document.getElementById("SM").value);
console.log(x)`enter code here`

```html
> <header><h1> Start
```

Comment: `x = 25` is assignment. Use `x === '25'` since you need an equality check, plus `value` will return a string, or use `.valueAsNumber` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
let x = document.getElementById("SM").value;
if (x == 25){
alert(x);
};
```

I think you said you want to `alert` the message. `console.log` only shows the message in developer tool, so use`alert`

Comment: Encouraging type conversion for new JS devs is not recommended.